# Vowpal Wabbit readable model weight interpretation

Tags: vowpalwabbit

Recently I'm using Vowpal Wabbit for classification, and I get a question about readable_model.

Here is my command: vw --quiet --save_resume --compressed aeroplane.txt.gzip --loss_function=hinge --readable_model aeroplane.txt

And the readable model file as below:

```
Version 7.7.0
Min label:-1.000000
Max label:1.000000
bits:18
0 pairs: 
0 triples: 
rank:0
lda:0
0 ngram: 
0 skip: 
options:
:1
initial_t 0.000000
norm normalizer 116869.664062
t 3984.000051
sum_loss 2400.032932
sum_loss_since_last_dump 2400.032932
dump_interval 1.000000
min_label -1.000000
max_label 1.000000
weighted_examples 3984.000051
weighted_labels 0.000051
weighted_unlabeled_examples 0.000000
example_number 2111
total_features 1917412
0:4.879771 0.004405 0.007933
1:5.268138 0.017729 0.020223
2:0.464031 0.001313 0.007443
3:3.158707 0.083495 0.029674
4:-22.006199 0.000721 0.004386
5:7.686290 0.018617 0.011562
......
1023:0.363004 0.022025 0.020973
116060:0.059659 2122.647461 1.000000
```

I have 1024 features for each example, and use i-1 as feature name for i feature.
My question is: Why I get 3 weights for each feature? Isn't it supposed to be only 1 weight? I'm a fresher to ML and get quite confused.

Answer (score 2):

Simple SGD (stochastic gradient descent) needs just one parameter per feature, the weight. However, VW uses `--adaptive --normalized --invariant` update by default.
So in addition to the weight, it needs to store two other parameters per feature:

- sum of gradients for `--adaptive` (AdaGrad-style update),
- per-feature regularization for `--normalized`.

These two additional parameters are stored in the model (readable or binary) only if `--save_resume` is provided.

What is strange that if you run `vw --sgd --save_resume`, the readable model still contains three parameters per feature, although `--sgd` effectively means not-adaptive, not-normalized and not-invariant. I think this is a bug in the implementation of `--readable_model`.

EDIT: This last strange behavior was a bug indeed and it is [fixed now](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/issues/596).